# Using one transaction across multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, java-ee-8

I want to write parallel into a database via my J2EE application using Hibernate.
I am using the `ThreadPoolExecutor` to generate and execute the threads.

The problem what I am facing is, that when one of the threads are failed, that the whole main transaction is rolled back. How can I achieve that the commit is made by the main thread and not by each of them?

Can I handle this by using  `ManagedExecutorService` and passing the same  `UserTransaction` through all threads?

Comment: can you provide some code?